# Twitter OAuth 1.0 authorization issue: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Oauth problem." (OAuthSwift)

Tags: swift, twitter, oauth

I am trying to authorize a user for my application via Twitter OAuth 1.0, utilizing a swift framework [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift) . Although everything seems fine (safari opens up with twitter page, app gets authorized, then redirection to my app occurs) I don`t get my oauth_token along with oauth_token_secret. Instead I get an error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Oauth problem."

```
let twitterConsumerKey = "********"
let twitterConsumerSecret = "***********************"
let twitterRequestTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
let twitterAuthorizeURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
let twitterAccessTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

let twitterAuth = OAuth1Swift(consumerKey: twitterConsumerKey,
                              consumerSecret: twitterConsumerSecret,
                              requestTokenUrl: twitterRequestTokenURL,
                              authorizeUrl: twitterAuthorizeURL,
                              accessTokenUrl: twitterAccessTokenURL)

twitterAuth.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/twitter")!, success: {
 credential,  response in
    println("///////////////////")
    println("OK")
    println(response)
    println(credential.oauth_token)
    println(credential.oauth_token_secret)
    println("///////////////////")
    }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in   // <--this method runs
        println("///////////////////")
        println("FAIL")
        println(error.localizedDescription) // <-- "The operation couldn’t be completed. Oauth problem."
        println("///////////////////")
})
```

Comment: May I recommend you use the Fabric library with TwitterKit to achieve this? No need to write everything from scratch when Twitter provides the tools to do it for you!

Comment: Thank you! I will definitly look into that right now, not really sure how I managed to completly miss it. However, the OAuthSwift framework states that it supports Twitter fully, so...